# Download APKs from GooglePlay using PHP/Node

Tags: php, node.js, google-play, apk

I want to download [APKs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package) from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en) using [PHP](http://php.net/) or [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) from my computer. How can I achieve this? Is it even possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [node-google-play](https://github.com/dweinstein/node-google-play) module for Nodejs solution